# differential equation : from Lagrange to Leibniz notation

Tags: derivatives, differential

I have this differential equation written in a Lagrange way (which I've bee taught):

$x''=a-bx-cx'$

I need to plug this into a computer software that seems to only understand the Leibniz notation.

Is this correct or am I wrong ?

$\frac{d^2x}{dt} = a-bx-c\frac{dx}{dt}$

Thanks

Comment: Yes this is correct, i would also write $$x''(t)$$ and so on.

Comment: Thanks very much. Well, the first notation is how I've been given the equation. So it's not up to me. So, given that first equation and how it has been provided (t isn't declared), do you see another better way to express it with the Leibniz notation ? "dy" instead of "dt" maybe ?

Comment: Leibniz used $$\frac{d x(t)}{dt}$$ and so on

Comment: Super thanks. How can I accept your answer please so that you gain benefit ?

Comment: You can give me points, ten or so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can try $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}$ instead of $\frac{d^2x}{dt}$.